# Controlling Scrollbar In Ant Design's Table Component

Tags: antd

I am using Ant Design's table component to display a large number of columns and while the default horizontal scrollbar is fine, I wanted to create some floating buttons that users can just click on to move the table left or right instead of dragging the horizontal scroll bar.

Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following example

App.jsx

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Table, Button, Tag, Space } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const tableContainerRef = useRef(null);

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "First Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name",
      render: (text) => <a>{text}</a>
    },
    {
      title: "Last Name",
      dataIndex: "lastname",
      key: "lastname",
      render: (text) => <a>{text}</a>
    },
    {
      title: "Phone no",
      dataIndex: "phoneno",
      key: "phoneno"
    },
    {
      title: "Age",
      dataIndex: "age",
      key: "age"
    },
    {
      title: "Address",
      dataIndex: "address",
      key: "address"
    },
    {
      title: "Tags",
      key: "tags",
      dataIndex: "tags",
      render: (_, { tags }) => (
        <>
          {tags.map((tag) => {
            let color = tag.length > 5 ? "geekblue" : "green";
            if (tag === "loser") {
              color = "volcano";
            }
            return (
              <Tag color={color} key={tag}>
                {tag.toUpperCase()}
              </Tag>
            );
          })}
        </>
      )
    },
    {
      title: "Action",
      key: "action",
      render: (_, record) => (
        <Space size="middle">
          <a>Invite {record.name}</a>
          <a>Delete</a>
        </Space>
      )
    }
  ];

  const data = [
    {
      key: "1",
      name: "John Brown",
      lastname: "Brown",
      phoneno: "865464543",
      age: 32,
      address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
      tags: ["nice", "developer"]
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      name: "Jim Green",
      lastname: "Green",
      phoneno: "865464543",
      age: 42,
      address: "London No. 1 Lake Park",
      tags: ["loser"]
    },
    {
      key: "3",
      name: "Joe Black",
      lastname: "Black",
      phoneno: "865464543",
      age: 32,
      address: "Sydney No. 1 Lake Park",
      tags: ["cool", "teacher"]
    }
  ];

  const handleScrollLeft = () => {
    tableContainerRef.current.scrollLeft -= 100;
  };

  const handleScrollRight = () => {
    tableContainerRef.current.scrollLeft += 100;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ overflowX: "auto" }} ref={tableContainerRef}>
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={data}
          style={{ minWidth: "1000px" }}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Space>
          <Button onClick={handleScrollLeft}> Scroll Left</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleScrollRight}>Scroll Right</Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Output:

[image: output]

**Note**: This is just a basic example, and you may need to modify it to fit your specific use case.